# ReferenceError: XFoo is not defined while creating custom element using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this [Custom Elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) article to learn HTML5. I'm trying very basic example of creating custom element which is mentioned in above article. but i don't know why i'm getting error

```
ReferenceError: XFoo is not defined while creating custom element using HTML5
```

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xFoo = document.createElement('x-foo');
xFoo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('Thanks!');
});
var xFoo = new XFoo();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<x-foo>hello</x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me to figure out small issue.

Comment: `xFoo` !== `XFoo`. Also I don't see a register. Also is there a note it is experimental. Also extending / adding the DOM with new custom elements is pretty crappy imho.

Comment: oh ya. my mistake.. i made it correct. but now i got TypeError: xFoo is not a constructor

Comment: Question Back: How do *you* understand the error? And please update your question with the new information to make it more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explaining: you have no constructor called `XFoo` that JS can use to create your custom element. As the tutorial you're following states, you need to *register* the new element:

```
var XFoo = document.register('x-foo');
```

This line at the beginning of your script should solve your problems.

Comment: document.register is not a function, i got this error if i include above code

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I need to know the version. The specification is supported since FF23, but the only one fully supporting these features is Chrome31

Comment: firefox 22.0
mozilla firefox for ubuntu canonical-1.0

Comment: It's quite clear why it is not working. Update FF to version 23 and you should be able to go